# Chat scroll won't go down, upon new message?

Tags: jquery

http://driptone.com/jony/applications/chat/index.php

When a new message happens, the scroll just goes up, while I have a method that will drag it down, if its on the bottom:

```
                element = $("#chat")[0];
                if (element.scrollTop == element.scrollHeight - element.height) {
                    element.scrollTop(element.scrollHeight);                
                }
```

While running this Interval:

```
        setInterval(function() {
                pingServer();   
                element = $("#chat")[0];
                if (element.scrollTop == element.scrollHeight - element.height) {
                    element.scrollTop(element.scrollHeight);                
                }               
        }, 5000);
```

It used to work before, I am not sure why did it stop working now.

***Any idea why did it stop?***

```
    function reload() {
            $.post("ajax.php", { loadMessages : "1" }, function(data) {
                    $(".discussion").html(data)
                    element = $("#chat")[0];
                    if (element.scrollTop == element.scrollHeight - element.height) {
                        element.scrollTop(element.scrollHeight);                
                    }                           
            });
    }
```

Reload function

Answer (score 0):

Your ping to the server is working asynchronously, and you are not calling your logic to adjust the scroll position on call back of this request.

Therefore, unless your ping responds instantly, your process flow is:

- Ping server
- Adjust scroll
- Response received from ping
- New messages added

Whereas you require:

- Ping server
- Response received from ping
- New messages added
- Adjust scroll

Therefore you need to call your scroll adjust in your call back after where you add the new messages.

---

> Any idea why did it stop?

My guess is your server response is now taking longer (perhaps you've moved in a production environment) and therefore your process flow is out of sync.

Comment: It only happens when the chat is low on messages

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems to work when I test in console:

```
var element = $("#chat")[0];
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
```

I don't think you need `if` condition, you never get inside it.

Comment: Yeah, but I aswell need it, cause if I scroll up, the chat will go down after someone posts, pretty annoying

Comment: Then use `$(element).height()` because `element.height` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just replacing element. with $(element). ?, Isn't it a variable?